# okd / openshift edge route with secrets

Tags: openshift, okd

I have OKD (openshift) project and when I create edge route to terminate HTTPS it works fine
here is YAML of edge route

```
apiVersion: route.openshift.io/v1
kind: Route
metadata:
  name: mydemo-route
  namespace: my-demo
spec:
  host: my-demo.com
  to:
    name: nginx-service
  port:
    targetPort: http
  tls:
    insecureEdgeTerminationPolicy: Redirect
    termination: edge
    certificate: |-
    -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
    ...
    -----END CERTIFICATE-----
    key: |
    -----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
    ...
    -----END PRIVATE KEY-----
    caCertificate: |-
    -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
    ...
    -----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

A problem arises when I want to use a secret to conceal private key.
Here is TLS secret:

> oc create secret tls my-demo-secret --cert=my-demo.key --key=my-demo.cer --namespace=my-demo

Lots of route examples didn't work, here is the error:

> oc get route

```
NAME          HOST/PORT                PATH   SERVICES        PORT   TERMINATION  WILDCARD 
mydemo-route  ExtendedValidationFailed        nginx-service   http   edge         None
```

here is one of faulty route.yaml that I tried:

```
apiVersion: route.openshift.io/v1
kind: Route
metadata:
  name: mydemo-route
  namespace: my-demo
spec:
  host: my-demo.com
  to:
    kind: Service
    name: nginx-service
  port:
    targetPort: http
  tls:
    termination: edge
    certificate: my-demo-secret
```

Any help would be appriciated

Answer (score 1):

You cannot reference a secret in a Route resource. The certificate and key need to be embedded in the resource itself.

---

You can create an [Ingress](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/) resource instead, with appropriate references to a secret, and OpenShift will convert this into a Route with the certificate and key embedded.

You can read more about this [here](https://cloud.redhat.com/blog/kubernetes-ingress-vs-openshift-route):

> Since the release of Red Hat OpenShift 3.10, ingress objects are supported alongside route objects. The Red Hat OpenShift ingress controller implementation is designed to watch ingress objects and create one or more routes to fulfill the conditions specified. If you change the ingress object, the Red Hat OpenShift Ingress Controller syncs the changes and applies to the generated route objects. These are then picked up by the built-in HAProxy load balancer.

---

I put together a [demo repository](https://github.com/larsks/cert-manager-routes-demo) recent that shows how to use this automatic conversion of Ingress resources to Routes to integrate with cert-manager.

Comment: Is there example like this not for LetsEncrypt but if you have 3 files certificate, key and intermediate ?

Comment: Just create a regular kubernetes Secret with `tls.key` and `tls.crt` keys (where the latter contains both the server certificate and the intermediate certificate). Reference that in your Ingress.